# Simple HTML table issue

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I'm coding in PHP and I code for simple HTML table. In that table the columns are editable and there is input `type=number` used to restrict from negative value entry in column names: Carton, Width, Depth, Height and Act columns.

But it's not working, creating problem with input `type="number"` and `min="0"` inside the html table.

Here is the link: http://sea.studioscue.in/test.php

Comment: Try creating phpfiddle for the same

Comment: Since the only evidence of a problem is your external live link, this question will not be helpful for future readers as soon as you have fixed it. It is therefore off-topic, and may be closed in the future. Please try to add evidence of the problem in the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just check the `validity.valid` property. This will be true if and only if the input falls within the range.
just add `oninput="validity.valid||(value='');"` to your input field.

```
<input type="number" oninput="validity.valid||(value='');" class="carton" min="0" value="" name="carton" maxlength="5" style="width:100px">
```