# Text fields disabled issues

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am working with PHP, and I coded a simple form with text and number fields. There is one field where `input type="number"` is disabled. I can't type any value there in that field. That field gets data automatically, but I want to type or change the value in that field.

The field's name is "Number Of Units" `input type="number" value="0" min="0"`.

Here is [the link to that form](http://sea.studioscue.in/import_client_quote_post.php).

Comment: there is no readonly condition used

Comment: _reply to me asap._ Mam first post proper problem statement

Comment: yes readonly is an attribute

Comment: & in my code  for that field no readonly attribute is applied

Comment: I posted [on your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41501077/simple-html-table-issue) that questions only featuring a link and no code are off-topic here. Three hours later, you post another one - can you just confirm that you are reading comments made on your questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your html of input,

```
<input class="form-control cartontot js-numbers" type="number" contenteditable="true" name="unit" id="unit" min="0" required="" placeholder="required" value="0" readonly="">
```

after removing `readonly` attribute at the end of your input html, replace below html with your html of that input

```
<input class="form-control cartontot js-numbers" type="number" contenteditable="true" name="unit" id="unit" min="0" required="" placeholder="required" value="0" >
```

And remember, `disabled` and `readonly` attributes are used to disable the input in html.

**EDIT**

```
    $('.pnm, .price, .subtot, .grdtot, .widtot, .perm, .tottot, .voltot, .vol, .tot, .vols, .cartontot, .widths, .depths, .heights, .acts').prop('readonly', true);
```

Check this code, written somewhere in your code, just remove `cartontot` this class from it

Comment: i checked my code line but there is no readonly attruibute used with that field see the actual code is this for that field                                            
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="volume" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Number Of Units</label>
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <input class="form-control cartontot js-numbers" type="number" contenteditable="true" name="unit" id="unit" min="0" required placeholder="required" value="0">
                </div>
           </div>

Comment: Check my edit section of answer

Comment: yes great its working . thank you so much sir thank you for your help. & I accept/use your idea of code & its working. & i will click on the button . thanks you once again.

Comment: You're most welcome !

Answer (score 1):

You can not change value of element if it is readonly or disabled. Try to remove readonly or disabled and then type anything.

Another option is you can do with Javascript or JQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Line 9 of your code:

```
$('.pnm, .price, .subtot, .grdtot, .widtot, .perm, .tottot, .voltot, .vol, .tot, .vols, .cartontot, .widths, .depths, .heights, .acts').prop('readonly', true);
```

This input element contains the class `cartontot`.
Your javascript is putting a readonly property on it.